# Sci-fi book or story written over 50 years ago about survivors from a destroyed Earth chased by aliens

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a sci-fi book or story written over 50 years ago. The backdrop to the story is that Earth has been destroyed and those who survived are being chased across the galaxy by the alien assailants.

The story is about one human spacecraft with humans, which lands on a planet when being chased by the assailants who destroyed Earth, and a third spacecraft, not from Earth, helps save the day for the occupants of the Earth spacecraft that is trying to escape the assailants.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Why was Earth destroyed?  Why did the other aliens help the humans?  Can you remember the cover art that went with this story?

Comment: That sounds *similar* to Greg Bear's [Anvil of Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anvil_of_Stars) from 1993, sequel to *The Forge of God*, except in *Anvil of Stars* the survivors are trying to find & destroy the assailants.

Comment: I don't recall that detail (of earth destruction) being described in the story.  The story all took place on a distant planet in the galaxy where the 3 spaceships (each with different beings) landed and interacted. Only action on that one foreign planet.  Anvil of Stars looks interesting but its not the story.  I read the story I am looking for over 50 years ago, when I was a teenager.  Sadly, I can not remember the cover art, nor the title, nor the author.